# some users are unable to see the entire page until going into edit mode and back out

Tags: document-library

Forgive me for not knowing what I'm really talking about, I've never used sharepoint before.

One of my clients (a school) has an intranet running on sharepoint, one page of the intreanet is a list of documents refering to a group of students. When users first load into the page the section that should show the list of files fails to load. We have found that if you go to edit the page (option in top right of page, I don't know if this is standard) and then exit edit mode then the page loads fully.

It happens in IE and Chrome which are the only two browsers in use here.

Has anyone else seen this issue before and been able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it might be overly aggressive Output Caching.  Go to `Site Settings - Site Collection Administration - Site Collection Output Cache` and look at the `Default Page Output Cache Profile`  If that is set to "Public Internet" then you probably want to set it to something else, like "Intranet"

If that looks normal, you might want to make sure that nobody has fiddled with the profiles themselves in `Site Collection Cache Profiles` and look at the settings for whichever profile was selected.  The most important settings are "Perform ACL check" and "Vary By User Rights" as these two set to No in an authenticated environment can easily cause the exact behavior you are describing.

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner. I'm only on site here once a week. I cannot see the site collection administration option anywhere.